# Migrate .NET website without access to IIS Server 1

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, migrate

I've been developing on an existing ASP.NET site for about a year now, but have not had to deal with any infrastructure issues beyond asking someone else to recycle an application pool, etc.  Things change, and now I need to copy the site to a new IIS server to do some performance testing without access to the original server.

High level steps?  After setting up a new site on the new IIS server, can I simply copy files and then start configuring?  Additionally, there are already several SharePoint sites on the new server... are there any considerations I should take?

Comment: What do you mean you have no access to the original server? Where are you getting the site from that you want to deploy on the new server?

Comment: I can access the file path and deploy code changes, but have no access to Windows Server 2003 or IIS for the 'original' site.  As a consequence, I'm assuming I have no ability to package the site, use WebDeploy, etc.  (My copy of the site is going on Windows Server 2008/IIS 7)

Comment: No, of course not. You can use MSDEPLOY just fine. We do it all the time, building our Web Application Projects with TFS 2010 Build. When you pass `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` to MSBUILD, it leaves the web package in the drop folder of the build, along with a .cmd file that will run MSDEPLOY for you.

Comment: There are definitely considerations you should take, but without knowledge of the server settings it could be difficult to know just what those considerations are. Literally ANY environment setting could be the difference between your application working, and not working. A few examples: IIS version, pipeline configurations (integrated?), AppPool identity, additional libraries installed (GAC or otherwise), folder permissions, registry settings. The list goes on, and on, and on.